# Receiving dangerous URL error with sanitization

Tags: angular, sanitization, html-sanitizing

I have an Angular template that loads an iframe with a dymanic URL.  Despite sanitizing the URL, I'm still receiving the error:

```
ERROR Error: Required a safe ResourceURL, got a URL
```

What am I missing?

**component.ts**

```
/**
 * Renders iframe for client to sign electronically by forming the URL based on the chosen externalDocument.
 * @param externalDocument
 */
selectDocument(externalDocument: IExternalDocument) {
  let document = new ExternalDocument(externalDocument)
  let url = document.url
  url = url.replace("INSERT_FIRSTNAME_HERE", this.firstName)
  url = url.replace("INSERT_LASTNAME_HERE", this.lastName)
  url = url.replace("INSERT_EMAIL_HERE", this.email)
  this.formattedUrl = url
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div style="display:block;margin:auto;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:12px!important;color:#AAA!important;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent;width:90%;">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="900" scrolling="yes" [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(formattedUrl)" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Those look like the names of Types, not any judgement call on the text value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` works instead of `bypassSecurityTrustUrl`